How do I fill an irregular shape created as a path with a hatching line pattern in Inkscape?
I have an irregular shape. I wanted to fill it with a line hatching pattern fill. I can do it with rectangles. But I cannot with irregular shapes.
My workflow was like this:
Click object (irregular shape) > Go to taskbar> "Object" Tab > "Pattern >" > "object to patterns"
This turns my irregular shape into an edgeless pattern fill that fills the whole rectangular selection area of the original shape.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The workflow you are describing will turn the shape into a pattern, not apply a pattern to a shape.  You are doing it backwards. Anyway, I've added an answer now.


Select the shape

Open the Stroke & Fill panel Shift+Ctrl+F

Go into the Fill tab

Hit the pattern button

Scroll down the list of patterns until you find one you like



You can also create your own custom patterns in Inkscape if you can't find one you like.
Draw a pattern, select it, and do Object > Pattern > Objects to Pattern. This will turn it into a custom pattern.
Then you will find it in the pattern dropdown, and you can apply to a shape as in the above steps.  You can scale the pattern and you can rotate it using the pattern controls.

